# How to store the user uploaded files in heroku?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-restful, yolo

I am working on object recognition project using flask and i have to store the uploaded images in a folder. I was trying to deploy it using heroku but i have no idea about how to store this images. So, can someone please tell me about storing the images and later on using it from the storage for detection?

Answer (score 2):

You can't store images on an app hosted on heroku. This is because after a couple hours, heroku "restarts" every app, wiping up every file that was created during execution time. That means that any file you upload on heroku, will be deleted at some point.

The only way to store images "on heroku" is to use a file storage addon, and i couldn't find any that was free.

[source](https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted)